# Multiple div inside caption tag

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to divide a `caption` area into 2 `div` each 50%, align the text to left on the left `div` and align the text to right on the other one. 
I cannot quite get the result I want, how can I fix this?

```css
.tcaption {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #cee7ff;
}

.tcaption-left-part {
  color: blue;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tcaption-right-part {
  color: blue;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-wrapper">
  <table class="ticket-table">
    <caption class="tcaption">
      <div class="tcaption-left-part">
        Ticket Details
      </div>
      <div class="tcaption-right-part">
        <a class=" btn btn-default " href="{% url 'ticket_edit' ticket.pk %} "><i class="fa fa-edit fa-2x "></i></a>
      </div>
    </caption>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Ticket Number:</td>
        <td>{{ticket.pk}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you display these as a table-cells (using the `display:table-cell` css) it'd make things easier. I didn't swap in a blue colour, but focused on your position problem.

You can probably afford to make the columns different widths if what you want is one column to be far-left aligned and the other to be aligned to the far right (or just have both close to 100% - not quite 100 cos of padding/margins). But I'll leave it for you to mess with. I put in span tags around the Ticket Details for better css control.

```css
.ticket-table, .tcaption {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--myBlue3);
}


.tcaption .left-part,
.tcaption .right-part {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50vh;
  color: var(--myBlue6);
  vertical-align:top;
}

.left-part, .left-part span {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  float:left;
}

.right-part, .right-part a {
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<div class="form-wrapper">
  <table class="ticket-table">
    <caption class="tcaption">
      <div class="left-part">
        <span>Ticket Details</span>
      </div>
      <div class="right-part">
        <a href='#' class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-2x">Ticket.pk</i></a>
      </div>
    </caption>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Ticket Number:</td>
        <td class="right-part">{{ticket.pk}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: somehow the 2 divs (right part and left part) are displayed on top of each other on my side, I am not sure there is any other CSS can affect this?

Comment: @ibo not sure what you mean, are they displayed incorrectly on your own website or what? Could you elaborate or add an image? Display properties can affect that.

Comment: ok, it is kind of working, I had to add `text-align:left;` to `.left-part`. the width of my table got increased that I did not want that. I am trying to figure out which line caused it

Comment: why do you have `.tcaption` while you changed the `tcaption` from a `class` to an `id`, is that a mistake?

Comment: @Ibo I adjusted my answer, yes my answer was askew initially. If you want the table to be narrower, adjust the ticket-table percentage

Comment: @ibo if you add the right-part css to your td, then the td on the right will right-align (if that's what you want)..

Comment: the problem was this line `width: 50vh;`,  it was forcing both right part and left part to fit into the caption and since they did not fit they were on top of each other, now everything looks good

Comment: @ibo super. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

That's because the `<caption>` is only as big as it's parent `<table>`. Increase the `width` of the `<table>` and you should get what you want.

```css
.tcaption {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #cee7ff;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

.tcaption-left-part {
  color: blue;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tcaption-right-part {
  color: blue;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-wrapper">
  <table class="ticket-table">
    <caption class="tcaption">
      <div class="tcaption-left-part">
        Ticket Details
      </div>
      <div class="tcaption-right-part">
        <a class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-2x">Right Aligned Text</i></a>
      </div>
    </caption>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Ticket Number:</td>
        <td>{{ticket.pk}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to change the width of table, this should be possible without doing it

Comment: @Ibo Then you must know that you are already doing what you want. It's just not visible as the fields are so close to each other. Try and put a `border` around them to see.